# Como rodar um applet em java no browser

Tags: java, navegador-de-internet, applet

Bom, eu fiz um programa em applet, (extendendo a classe de JApplet) e gerei o arquivo .jar, coloquei ele numa pasta e escrevi uma página HTML para roda-lo:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head><title>Engineer's Showdown</title>
</head>

<body style="background-color:black;">
<center>
    <applet code="pack.game.Applet.class" archive="engineers_applet.jar" width="1024" height="768"
    style="color:white;">
    Applet tag
    </applet>
    <br/>
    <object archive="engineers_applet.jar" classid="java:pack.game.Applet.class" codetype="application/java"
    width="1024" height="768" style="color:white;">
    Object tag
    </object>
</center>
</body>
```

Ao acessar o site, o applet simplesmente não roda, quando aperto F12 para ver o console, também não aparece nada, caso também seja util, aqui vai minha classe Applet.java:

```
package pack.game;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Cursor;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseWheelListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.VolatileImage;
```

import javax.swing.JApplet;

import engine.window.Manager;
import engine.window.Painel;
import engine.window.Window;
import pack.objects.Res;
import pack.states.Ending;
import pack.states.Game;
import pack.states.Menu;

public class Applet extends JApplet implements Runnable, KeyListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, MouseWheelListener{

`/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
Thread thread;
VolatileImage img;
Graphics2D g;
double delta;
double FPS = 60;
double targetTime = 1000.0/FPS;

public void start(){
    img = createVolatileImage(1024, 768);
    g = img.createGraphics();
    setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    thread = new Thread(this);
    addKeyListener(this);
    addMouseListener(this);
    addMouseMotionListener(this);
    addMouseWheelListener(this);
    thread.start();

    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    Window.width = 1024;
    Window.height = 768;
}

public void init(){
    Main.loadPonyAnimations();
    Main.loadWeaponImages();
    Res.load();
    // Transparent 16 x 16 pixel cursor image.
    BufferedImage cursorImg = new BufferedImage(16, 16, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

    // Create a new blank cursor.
    Cursor blankCursor = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createCustomCursor(
        cursorImg, new Point(0, 0), "blank cursor");

    setCursor(blankCursor);

    Manager.addState(new Menu());
    Manager.addState(new Game());
    Manager.addState(new Ending());
}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, null);
}

public void run() {
    long startTime;
    long elapsedTime;
    initialize();
    while(true){
        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        update();
        draw();
        elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;

        while(elapsedTime/1000000.0 < targetTime){
            elapsedTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
        }
        delta = (System.nanoTime() - startTime)/1000000.0;
    }
}

public void initialize(){
    Manager.init();
}

public void update(){
    Manager.update((float) delta);
}

public void draw(){
    g.setColor(Color.black);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, Window.width, Window.height);
    g.setColor(Color.white);
    Manager.draw(g);
    repaint();
}

public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent m) {
    Painel.MouseX = m.getX();
    Painel.MouseY = m.getY();
}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse foi movimentado dentro da tela
 */
public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent m) {

    Painel.MouseX = m.getX();
    Painel.MouseY = m.getY();

}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse foi clicado
 */
public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent m) {
}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse entrou na tela
 */
public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent m) {

    Painel.MouseX = m.getX();
    Painel.MouseY = m.getY();

}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse saiu da tela
 */
public void mouseExited(MouseEvent m) {

    Painel.MouseX = m.getX();
    Painel.MouseY = m.getY();

}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse foi pressionado
 */
public void mousePressed(MouseEvent m) {
    Manager.mousePressed(m.getButton());
}
/**
 * Recebe quando o mouse foi solto
 */
public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent m) {
    Manager.mouseReleased(m.getButton());
}
/**
 * Recebe quando uma tecla foi pressionada
 */
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    Manager.keyPressed(e);
}
/**
 * Recebe quando uma tecla foi solta
 */
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    Manager.keyReleased(e);
}
/**
 * Recebe quando uma tecla foi digitada
 */
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent m) {
    Manager.mouseWheelMoved(m);
}`

}

Também um print da página, e da minha pasta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu estou fazendo de errado? Eu preciso fazer algo com esse .jar antes?

Comment: A não ser que você tenha uma necessidade muito específica para usar applets, simplesmente **não use**.

Answer (score 1):

> O Chrome não oferece mais suporte à NPAPI (tecnologia necessária para applets Java)

Fonte: https://www.java.com/pt_BR/download/faq/chrome.xml

Comment: Embora este link possa responder à pergunta, é melhor incluir as partes essenciais da resposta aqui e fornecer o link para referência.  As respostas apenas por link podem ser invalidadas se a página com o link for alterada. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/49535)

Comment: Bem lembrado, Wallace, foi por isso que eu escrevi "O Chrome não oferece mais suporte à NPAPI (tecnologia necessária para applets Java)".

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Acho que a resposta é realmente apenas isto, não tem muito o que dizer, o máximo que o André poderia editar é dizer que este suporte foi removido no *Google Chrome 45 e navegadores que usam Chromium também tiveram o suporte removido. Seria mais pra detalhar.